# React not replacing content in div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying out basic react apps and I'm trying to get react running. There is a div tag in index.ejs which holds content. Initially, I had set content to '...' in my server.js file. When I add react code, in the index.js file located in source folder, the value displayed in div tag should change but it isn't. Please help

server.js :

```
import config from './config';
import apiRouter from './api';
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs'
const server = express();

server.set('view engine','ejs');

server.get('/',(req,res) => {
      res.render('index', {
    content: '....'
});
});
server.use('/api', apiRouter);
server.use(express.static('public'));

server.listen(config.port,() => {
    console.info('Express listening on port', config.port)
});
```

index.ejs :

```
<%- include('header') -%>
<div id ="root"><%- content -%></div>
<%- include('footer') -%>
```

header.ejs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello EJS+</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>
</html>
```

footer.ejs:

```
<script type="/bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement('h2',null,'Hello React'), 
    document.getElementbyId('root') 
 );
```

Comment: Are you using [react-dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) to render your app into "root"?

Comment: I am, added the react code in my post

Answer (score 1):

The correct is document.getElement**B**yId('root').

If it still does not work, check if your `index.js` and 'react'/'react-dom' lib files are being loaded in page (bundle.js).

Also, always check your console in Developer Tools in your browser for error in front-end.

Comment: I changed it to document.getElementById('root') and checked the index.js file. I lib files are getting loaded.